# How to cache a table (MySQL) using Tomcat Server for lookup data

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, caching, spring-mvc

My application needs to cache the lookup data into server memory so that the data will be returned immediatly with-out accessing the DB.

Whenever there is an insert or update operation happened for lookup table, either server re-start should cache/sync up the data or I would like to refresh the cache using some admin tool (some authenticated JSP page with some backend logic to access the cache/db).

I am developing the application using Spring MVC.

Please suggest how can I achieve this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the admin part, but you might want to look at Spring's cache abstraction, via the @Cacheable annotation.

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html